# Явное задание шаблонного параметра конструктора

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Допустим, есть класс с конструктором. У конструктора есть шаблонный параметр:

```
template<typename T> class A {
    T v;
public:
    template<typename U> A(T p,U u) : v(p)
    {
        std::cout << u << v << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Тип `U` может быть выведен:

```
int main()
{
    A<int> b(2,'A');            // Ok, U = char
    auto x = A<int>::A(1,'A');  // Ok, U = char
}
```

А можно ли задать его явно, не через аргумент конструктора? Как-то так:

```
int main()
{
    A<int,char> b(2,'A');   // не работает
    A<int><char> b(2,'A');  // не работает
    auto y= A<int>::A<char>(2, 'A');   // не работает
}
```

Comment: Нельзя. Параметры шаблона перечисляются после его имени, а у конструкторов нет имени.

Comment: А  зачем вам то, что  абсолютно не имеет отношение к нормальному явлению?

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan А что тут ненормального? У меня есть два параметр пака. Один надо передать в аргумент конструктора базового класса, а другой - в функцию, которая вызывается в конструкторе производного класса. Попытавшись это сделать, я столкнулся с тем, что сделать это нельзя, т.к. нельзя явно записать тип `U`

Comment: @AVK, не нормально,  ваше желание _ задать параметр шаблона можно только если есть такой шаблон. По мне вы думаете не в том направлении. То , что вы хотите совершенно ни к чему, просто передайте этот параметр. Если речь идет о rebind, то напишите шаблон структуры  rebind и в ней определите псевдоним other = A<U>. А еще лучше если в вопросе представите  что вы конкретно хотите делать, из за которого был задан вопрос, тогда можно будет предложить варианты как это лучше делать

Comment: В таком виде вопрос  не поясняет цели(ИМХО)

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan "параметр шаблона можно только если есть такой шаблон" - он есть. И то, что его параметр нельзя явно задать, по-моему, странно. Как заметил @AlexGlebe, у любой шаблонной функции-члена можно задать параметр, а у конструктора нельзя почему-то. "Если речь идет о rebind," - а можно у вас попросить ссылку, что это такое? `std:bind` знаю (но не вижу, как он здесь поможет), ребинд не знаю

Comment: Приведите-ка для обычного класса *вызов конструктора*. Именно *явный вызов*, и именно конструктора. Раз функция-член ничем не отличается от конструктора...

Comment: @AVK, жаль, вы не поняли, и про  std:bind я ничего не говорил. Именем   rebind  обычно называют структуру для перевязывания  к другому параметру

Answer (score 3):

У конструкторов нельзя выбирать, а простых методов можно. Просто укоротите конструктор функционально и вызовите шаблонный метод.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
template<typename T> 
class A {
    T v;
public:
  A(T p) : v(p) { }
  template<typename U>
  A & Constructor(U u){
    std::cout << u <<' '<< v << std::endl; 
    return * this ;
  }
} ;

int main (){

  A<int>(1).Constructor<double>(3);

  A<int> a(2) ;
  a.Constructor<char>('4'); 

}
```

*Это просто принцип. А теперь красота:*

---

Для красоты можете создать шаблонный класс только для конструкторов :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
template<typename T> 
class A {
    T v;
protected :
  A(T p) : v(p) { }
  template<typename U>
  A & Constructor(U u){
    std::cout << u <<' '<< v << std::endl; 
    return * this ;
  }
} ;

template<typename T,typename U> 
class B : public A<T> {
public:
    B ( T v , U u ) : A<T> ( v ) {
        A<T>::Constructor(u);
    }
} ;

int main (){
  B<char,double> b ( '1' , 2.5 ) ;
  A<char> & a = b ; 
}
```

Объект `B` включает в себя класс `A` и он будет работать точно так-же как и класс `A`. Вызов внутренних шаблонных методов будет спрятан от глаз пользователя.

Comment: Так я умею :) Некрасиво я и сам могу...

Comment: ну может ещё кто-то придумает покрасивее. Например `variant` аргументами ..

Answer (score 1):

В таком виде - нет. Но можно, если измените сигнатуру шаблона.
Сделайте параметр шаблона конструктора параметром шаблона всего класса.

```
template<typename T, typename U> 
class A 
{
    T v;
public:
    A(T p,U u) : v(p)
    {
        std::cout << u << v << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A<int,char> b(2,'A');   // работает
    A c(3,'A'); // автовыведение типа
}
```

Comment: @AVK Но учтите, что в этом случае надо будет писать оба типа, например, при вызове конструктора по умолчанию. А типы с разными `U` будут разными, несовместимыми типами.

Comment: Это понятно. Но тогда тип будет другой, а мне это не надо

Answer (score 1):

В продолжение идеи [AlexGlebe](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1491592/529836). Так нельзя забыть вызвать `Constructor`:

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
class A {
    T v;
    A(T p) : v(p) { } //Приватный конструктор
public:
    template<typename U>
    static A constructor(T p, U u){
        A out(p);
        //Constructor
        std::cout << u <<' '<< out.v << std::endl;
        return out;
    }
};

int main (){
    A<int> a = A<int>::constructor<char>(2,'A');
    return 0;
}
```